# Android getBaseContext() for database constructor

Tags: android

I have 2 separate classes for my android application to insert data to sqllite database

1. DataBaseAdapterClass with this constructor

   ```
   public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

   }
   ```
2. I'm using another class called webservise  to get data from web service and insert in sqllite databse, there for i use this Asyntask Class..

   ```
   public class FoodCityWebService {

       String myValue = "";
       private final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
       private final String URL = "xxxxxx:xxxx/Service1.asmx?WSDL";

       public FoodCityWebService(){

       }

       public FoodCityWebService(String param1){

       }

       public String getValueFromService()
       {
           myValue =  new web().execute("df").toString();
           return myValue;
       }



       public class web extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, String>
       { 
             String result = "";
             final String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/GetUserName";
           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

               final String METHOD_NAME="GetUserName";

               SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
               request.addProperty("name","Bread");
               SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//ver11 version
               envelop.dotNet=true;//only for dotnet       
               envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                HttpTransportSE httptransportse=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                String x ="";
               try{
               httptransportse.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelop);

               SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)envelop.getResponse();



                   x = response.toString();

                   DatabaseAdapter da = new DatabaseAdapter(); // *ERROR!!!*           
                   da.addItem(new Item("CityItem1","Bread",Double.parseDouble(x),"222"));



               }catch (Exception e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();

               }

               return x;


           }


           } 


    }
   ```

How do I create the object from databseAdapter Class?

Comment: You need to pass it the application context in the foodcity constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I create the object from databseAdapter Class?

One basic approach is to add a Context to the parameters of your constructor and save it as a member variable:

```
private Context mContext;
public FoodCityWebService(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}
```

Then use:

```
DatabaseAdapter da = new DatabaseAdapter(mContext);
```